# Passing User_ID through new_item form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I have a simple app that allows users to create 'items'. On the _form, the only data that it asks for is 'content' and 'user_id', which is currently a number picker that assigns user_id to the item for ownership. But what I want to do is have the form assume that the user_id is the current user's ID (using Devise). That way other people can't assign 'items' to other users. Make sense? Here's the form.

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@item) do |f| %>
  <% if @item.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@item.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this item from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @item.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :user_id %><br />
    <%= f.number_field :user_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You don't even need user_id in the form, you can just have the content text_field. In the controller you can use current_user.id to create your items.

Comment: in your controller, instead of `Item.new`, use `current_user.items.build`

Comment: I tried to delete the user_id div section from the form, but when I tried to create a new item, it spat this out at me...

NoMethodError in ItemsController#show

undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
Rails.root: C:/Sites/railsprojects/scratch

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/items_controller.rb:17:in `show'
Request

Parameters:

{"id"=>"10"}
Show session dump

Show env dump

Response

Headers:

None

Comment: I think it's actually creating the items, though. When I try to load the master listing of the items, now... items/index... it gives me this, which leads me to believe that it's allowing the item creation but it's saving nil for some of the fields...

RuntimeError in Items#index

Showing C:/Sites/railsprojects/scratch/app/views/items/index.html.erb where line #17 raised:

Item#email delegated to user.email, but user is nil: #<Item id: 6, content: "New test item", user_id: nil, created_at: "2013-02-25 00:04:59", updated_at: "2013-02-25 00:04:59">

Answer (score 0):

You should be working with associations from the model.

example your Items model should have `belongs_to :user`

then your would just use the `:user` method not the `user_id` attribute.

But you really could make this much more simpler.

install simple_forms gem it will make your life easier.

```
gem "simple_form"
```

then

```
<%= simple_form_for(@item) do |f| %>

    <%= f.input :content %>

    <%= f.association :user %>

    <%= f.button :submit %>

<% end %>
```